# Creating a hierarchical structure from a list of sequence strings

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, hierarchical

Given a list of sequence strings, what's the best way to create a hierarchical structure from it?

A sample of the type of list of sequence strings is below:

```
List<string> sequenceList = new List<string>() { "1", "1.1", "1.2", "2", "2.1", "2.1.1", "2.1.2" };
```

I've included an initial pass of the code below too:

```
public class Hierarchy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}

public IList<Hierarchy> GetHierarchy(IList<string> sequenceList)
{
    int iD = 0;
    List<Hierarchy> hierarchy = new List<Hierarchy>();

    foreach (string sequence in sequenceList)
    {
        iD++;
        List<string> childSequence = new List<string>();

        string[] sequenceParts = sequence.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // If the sequence contains sub-sequence, i.e. "2.1" is a sub-sequence of "2".
        if (sequenceParts.Count() > 1)
        {
            // Struggling with this part, how to obtain the child sequence...
            childSequence = sequenceList.Where(s => s.Substring(0, (s.Length - 2)) == sequence.Substring(0, (s.Length - 2))).ToList();

            if (childSequence.Count() > 0)
            {
                int parentID = iD;
                foreach (string subSequence in childSequence)
                    hierarchy.Add(new Hierarchy() { ID = iD, ParentID = parentID });
            }
        }
        else
            // Add top level.
            hierarchy.Add(new Hierarchy() { ID = iD, ParentID = 0 });
    }

    return (IList<Hierarchy>)hierarchy;
}
```

I suspect I'm missing a trick with recursion on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have some odd design issues.  What would be the parentID of "2.1.1"?  And what would it's ID be?  Wouldn't the design be `public class Hierarchy { public string ID { get; set;} public List<Hierarchy> Children {get;set;}}`?

Comment: The ID of "2.1.1" would be 6 and it's ParentID would be 5, "2.1". I understand what you mean but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help a bit to add Sequence property to the class and use it to find the parent:

```
public class Hierarchy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
}

public static IList<Hierarchy> GetHierarchy(IList<string> sequenceList)
{
    int iD = 0;
    List<Hierarchy> hierarchy = new List<Hierarchy>();

    foreach (string sequence in sequenceList)
    {
        iD++;
        List<string> childSequence = new List<string>();

        string[] sequenceParts = sequence.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // If the sequence contains sub-sequence, i.e. "2.1" is a sub-sequence of "2".
        if (sequenceParts.Count() > 1)
        {
            var parentSequence = sequence.Substring(0, sequence.LastIndexOf("."));
            var parent = hierarchy.Single(x => x.Sequence == parentSequence);

            hierarchy.Add(new Hierarchy() { ID = iD, ParentID = parent.ID, Sequence = sequence });
        }
        else
            // Add top level.
            hierarchy.Add(new Hierarchy() { ID = iD, ParentID = 0, Sequence = sequence });
    }

    return (IList<Hierarchy>)hierarchy;
}
```

EDITED: this version uses recursion

```
public class Hierarchy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}

public static IList<Hierarchy> GetHierarchy(IList<string> sequenceList)
{
    int iD = 0;
    List<Hierarchy> hierarchy = new List<Hierarchy>();

    foreach (string sequence in sequenceList.Where(x => x.Count(f => f == '.') == 0)) // get the root nodes
    {
        iD++;

        var item = new Hierarchy() { ID = iD, ParentID = 0 };
        hierarchy.Add(item);
        hierarchy.AddRange(GetChildsRecursive(sequence, item.ID, sequenceList, () => ++iD));
    }

    return (IList<Hierarchy>)hierarchy;
}

private static IList<Hierarchy> GetChildsRecursive(string parentSequence, int parentId, IList<string> sequences, Func<int> idGenerator)
{
    var parentDots = parentSequence.Count(f => f == '.');
    var childSequences = sequences.Where(x => x.StartsWith(parentSequence) && x.Count(f => f == '.') == parentDots + 1);

    var list = new List<Hierarchy>();
    foreach (var childSequence in childSequences)
    {
        var item = new Hierarchy() { ID = idGenerator(), ParentID = parentId };
        list.Add(item);
        list.AddRange(GetChildsRecursive(childSequence, item.ID, sequences, idGenerator));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This solution did work perfectly. I do wonder if there is a more concise solution, using recursion? However this solution does what I wanted it to do. Thanks.

Comment: Added a version, now with recursion. The code is a little longer, mainly because the recursion is moved to a new method.